# passing root path in move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, document-root

i have a constant variable named SADMIN

```
define('SADMIN','http://localhost/synthesis_study_material/student_admin/');
```

and i am trying to use SADMIN constant in my move_uploaded_file function

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['name']['tmp_name'], SADMIN."include/uploaded/epub/".$_POST['name']);
```

my current file is in

```
http://localhost/synthesis_study_material/synthesis_notes_admin/index.php
```

file is not getting uploaded in expected folder and move_uploaded_file is not giving any warning or error

Comment: "Not working" is not an adequate description of the problem for anyone to be able to offer you help.

Comment: Destination of move_uploaded_file needs to be a file path, not a url

Comment: what should i do if i want to to upload file in other directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destination of move_uploaded_file needs to be a file path, not a url. To clarify this your webserver has a specified folder on the file system set as the web root. This might be something like '/var/www'. This means when you go to 'http://localhost/' it will look for a file such as '/var/www/index.php' or '/var/www/index.php'.

the destination might be an absolute path or relative, so you might supply 'synthesis_study_material/student_admin/' and that might be the same as '/var/www/synthesis_study_material/student_admin/' (depending on your web root and where move_uploaded_file is called from). Note you can use `dirname(__FILE__)` to get the path of the current php file. Also note that move_uploaded_file will not create directories for you if they don't exist.

I suggest starting with a simple example such as `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['name']['tmp_name'], 'test-upload.txt');` to see if anything gets uploaded, and make modifications from there.